# np.set_printoptions(formatter={'int':hex})

Tags: python, numpy

Я конвертирую numpy массив в шестнадцатеричные числа

```
np.set_printoptions(formatter={'int':hex})
np.array([1,2,3, 65535])
```

Получаю такой вывод:

```
array([0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0xffff])
```

Однако, мне необходимо наличие "ведущих нулей", то есть, чтобы я получал массив вида:

```
array([0x0001, 0x0002, 0x0003, 0xffff])
```

То есть, чтобы после 0x шло ровно 4 символа (Я не перехожу границу 0xffff).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно добавить соответствующее форматирование:

```
np.set_printoptions(formatter={'int': lambda x:"{:#06x}".format(x)})
np.array([1,2,3, 65535])
```

Вывод:

```
array([0x0001, 0x0002, 0x0003, 0xffff])
```